# How to profile a class inside a jar?

Tags: java, jar, profiling, executable-jar, hprof

If I have a class inside a JAR (compiled with `mvn assembly:assembly`) which I'm trying to profile, what's the command to get a valid core dump which I can use with jhat or the Eclipse Memory Analyzer?

I tried running this:

`java -agentlib:hprof=heap=sites,cpu=samples,file=profile.hprof,format=b -jar the-jar.jar`

and the core dump is created when I stop the process.

But neither jhat or the Eclipse Memory Analyzer recognize this as a valid dump.

jhat gives me this warning:

```
Resolving 0 objects...
WARNING:  hprof file does not include java.lang.Class!
WARNING:  hprof file does not include java.lang.String!
WARNING:  hprof file does not include java.lang.ClassLoader!
```

Also reading through the hprof documentation, I see that I must pass the class name. How do I do that when it's inside the JAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact the the class was loaded from a JAR file is not relevant for the heap dump.

You can use `jmap` to get usable HPROF heap dumps without modifying the start command.

```
jmap -heap:format=b <pid>
```

where  is the process id that you can get the with the `jps` command line utility. Both executables are part of the JDK.